# Chrome getting crashed with my simple GWT Application

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, crash, google-chrome-devtools, crash-dumps

I have written a simple gwt application, and when i am using it in chrome browser, it is getting crashed.

So i debug chrome using windbg tool to take dump. And here is my dump..

```
(cc0.15d8): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\33.0.1750.154\chrome_child.dll - 
eax=00000068 ebx=00000000 ecx=6dc299a6 edx=0b73a067 esi=0044d770 edi=01a6d000
eip=6daf00d3 esp=0044d750 ebp=0044d750 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000206
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0xb4d33f:
6daf00d3 cc              int     3
7:044> g


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
#
(cc0.15d8): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000001 ebx=00000000 ecx=6d212db0 edx=ff61f000 esi=6e67b598 edi=0044d754
eip=6d51ff03 esp=0044d734 ebp=0044d740 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x57d16f:
6d51ff03 cc              int     3
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
7:044> g
(cc0.15d8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=2ea08261 ebx=00000044 ecx=00000004 edx=01a6d000 esi=0044ded8 edi=00000010
eip=6cffd8db esp=0044dde0 ebp=0044de08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
chrome_child!ovly_debug_event+0x5ab47:
6cffd8db 8903            mov     dword ptr [ebx],eax  ds:002b:00000044=????????
```

Please correct me if i am going wrong to find solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, PK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should load the right symbols of program,otherwise you cannot figure out in which function the exception occurs.For example :  if you load the right symbol in windbg,the windbg will tell you the exception occurs in the function  FOO()+0x12,otherwise it will tell that you should check the position MAIN()+0x1234 which also point to FOO()+0x12 but have less meaning to human being.

so the first step to take is loading the right debug symbols.

Comment: Hi @theliam911 , Thanks for your replay. I didn't get the exact meaning of right symbol. Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: In a short word,your dump was generate by Application's release version,there is less valuable information for us to detect the problem than the debug version.If using the debug version of dump file  we can figure out the problem quickly.

Comment: Hey @theliam911 , Thanks for your quick response. But i have got some memory leak in my application. And i found it using chrome profiler!!